# Basic javascript on codePen

Tags: javascript, codepen

In localhost, this very simple code has no issue but it doesn't work on codePen? (the color background should change when the button is clicked)

https://codepen.io/jmercier/pen/mdvzJEV

The hover states of my button doesn't work on codePen and the javaascript is ignored.

Why?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

        :root {
            --bg-color: #F5F5F5;
            --text-color: #000;
            --bg-hover: green;
            --text-hover: white;
        }

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box
        }

        body {
            transition: background-color 2s;
            background: var(--bg-color);
            color: var(--text-color);
            font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
        }

        #container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .title {
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 1.5rem;
        }

        .sstitle {
            font-weight: 300;
            font-size: 0.825rem;
            letter-spacing: .5rem;
        }

        .btn {
            border: none;
            padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
            margin-top: 1rem;
            background: var(--text-color);
            color: var(--bg-color);
        }

        .btn:hover {
            background: var(--bg-hover);
            color: var(--text-hover);
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <p class="title">Hello World</p>
        <p class="sstitle">Welcome</p>
        <button class="btn" id="btn">Changing Color</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        let state = 0;
        let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        btn.addEventListener("click", toogleLight)
        function toogleLight() {
            if(state===0){
                document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--bg-color","black");
                document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--text-color","#F5F5F5");
                state = 1;
            } else{
                document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--bg-color","#F5F5F5");
                document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--text-color","black");
                state = 0;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

the color background should change when the button is clicked

Comment: It is working as expected for me. which browser and version are you using?

Comment: Its working when i hover over the button. Are you using some new browser?

Comment: Suggestion: **1.** load the site, **2.** press `ctrl` + `F5` to clear the cache and refresh the page, **3.** does it work now, or does it still not work?

Comment: Chrome Version 119.0.6045.159 (Build officiel) (x86_64)

Comment: Ho yes, I've just update Chrome and it's OK, thank you!

Comment: You may wish to close the question then, otherwise it's likely to be closed as a "typo or not reproducible," which affects your reputation, or rate-limits your ability to ask questions (I'm not quite sure what the consequences *are*, but it seems better to be avoided) :)